# Issue with jbehave example table

Tags: java, jbehave

I am working on automation in jbehave. I have scenario in which i have multiple steps. Now out of that 2 steps are having same input parameter name. For one i am passing value from examples table and for other i am passing value in statement itself even though it is taking value from example table only.

I know i can change the input parameter name in java/jbehave statement but that is not possible because both the statements are used at multiple times and for one scenario i can not break all existing scenarios.

Any clue on this or anyone who faced similar situation should also comment on this.

code snippet

story file

`Scenario :`

`Given I pass value '1'`

`And I take value from temp file '<value>'`

`Examples`

`value |`

`2`

java file :

```
@Given("I pass value '$value'")
public void fn(@Named("value") int value)
{
------
}

@Given("I take value from temp '$value'")
public void fn2(@Named("value") int value)
{
-----
}
```

Now the issue here is that for first statement even though i am passing value '1' from statement it is taking value from example table only which is '2'.

Comment: I have updated question.

Comment: Which version of JBehave do you use ? I tested your case in the latest version, and it worked as expected.

Comment: @kordirko  I am using 3.9.5. Latest version I saw is 4.0.4. Can you please provide your test file with which you successfully run this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I tested a similar scenario on versions 3.9.5 and 4.0.4 of JBehave, and it worked fine on both versions.
This is my scenario:

```
Scenario: some scenario

Given I pass value '1'

Given I take value from temp file '<value>'

Examples: 
|value|
|2|
|3|
```

and here is my java code:

```
public class MySteps {

    @Given("I pass value '$value'")
    public void fn(int value)
    {
       System.out.println("GIVEN : I pass value = " + value);
    }

    @Given("I take value from temp file '$value'")
    public void fn2( @Named("value") int value)
    {
        System.out.println("GIVEN : I take value from temp = " + value);
    }
}
```

I have created a project in Eclipse using maven `jbehave-simple-archetype`.
You can clone this project into Eclipse from this link: https://github.com/kordirko/jb_test

To change a version just edit it in pom.xml => `<jbehave.core.version>3.9.5</jbehave.core.version>`

========== EDIT ================
Consider setting `useDelimiterNamedParameters(true)` option in JBehve configuration
http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/parametrised-scenarios.html
They write in documentation, that starting from version 4.0.4 this option is enabled by default.

> We can configure JBehave to interpret the name contained between the delimiters as the parameter name and look it up in the parameters provided by the examples table. The default behaviour of parameter lookup is overridden via the ParameterControls:

```
new MostUsefulConfiguration()
        .useParameterControls(new ParameterControls().useDelimiterNamedParameters(true));
```

> In this mode, the step method would look much simplified:

```
@Given("a stock of $symbol and a $threshold")
public void aStock(String symbol, double threshold) {
    // ...
}
```

> Starting from version 4.0, the use of delimiter named parameters is the default behaviour.

---

I tested this option and it seemed to work both in 3.9.5 and 4.0.4 versions.
This is a test scenario:

```
Scenario: some scenario

Given I pass value '1'
Given I pass value '<value>'

........

Examples: 
|value|
|2|
|3|
```

and a java method **without @Named annotation**:

```
   @Given("I pass value '$value'")
    public void fn(int value)
    {
       System.out.println("GIVEN : I pass value = " + value);
    }
```

The first step `Given I pass value '1'` is taking `1` as a parameter.
The second step `Given I pass value '<value>'` matches `<value>` by name with a column named `<value>` from the example table, and is taking values from this table.

Comment: In first function "fn" you have not mentioned parameter with @Named. If you do the same as second function, I guess you will get the same issue that I am facing.

I missed that part in question itself, i have edited the same in question.

Comment: @Pratik Zinzuvadiya I've added to the answer a solution to this issue using `useDelimiterNamedParameters(true));` parameter.